# Telegram bot inline keyboard markup can not received callback data JSON in google sheet when I use Google Apps Script

Tags: node.js, json, google-apps-script, telegram-bot

I use "Google Apps Script" to develop my telegram bot and I want to create a inline keyboard to receive users response data, so I have reference the telegram bot api "https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#available-methods" and create a function to do that,but Why I click the inline keyboard in my telegram bot, the google sheet table can not received the "callback_data" value ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFqO1.jpg)

Thanks!

```js
function start(estringa){
    
    
    var InlineKeyboardMarkup = {
          inline_keyboard : [
        [   
          {"text":"A",'callback_data': "chinese"},
          {"text":"B",'callback_data': "english"}
        ],
        [
          {"text":"C",'callback_data': "japanese"},
          {"text":"D",'callback_data': "korean"}
        ]
      ]
    }

  var id = estringa.message.chat.id.toFixed()
  var payload;
  
  if (estringa.message.text){ 
      payload = {
          "method": "sendMessage",
          "chat_id": id,
          "text": '想到哪個網站呢？' ,
          'reply_markup': JSON.stringify(InlineKeyboardMarkup)
          
      } 
  }

  else {
    payload = {
      "method": "sendMessage",
      "chat_id": id,
      "text": "hello world!"
    }
   }
  return payload // 返回程式碼上層，重複執行判斷
  
}
```